# Download private BitBucket repository zip file using http authentication

Tags: git, http, bitbucket

I'm writing a script to easily deploy an application. The code for the application is stored in a private BitBucket repository.

I'd like to be able to download a zip file of the commit. I've tried authenticating with the following code:

`https://user:pass@bitbucket.org/user/repo/get/commit.zip`

However, instead of accomplishing the task it redirects to the login page on BitBucket.

Answer (score 36):

Personally, I didn't want to put my password into my script to accomplish this. So the trick was to run the following command, after adding your public key to your bitbucket account:

```
git archive --remote=ssh://git@bitbucket.org/your_bitbucket_username/your_repository.git --format=zip --output="name_of_your_desired_zip_file.zip" master
```

I have multiple keys on my system, if you do too, you will want to create a config file within your ~/.ssh directory that specifies to use a specific key for bitbucket connections.

**~/.ssh/config**

```
Host bitbucket.org
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  IdentityFile /home/me/.ssh/my_private_key
```

Comment: This is just the way to do, any other way to authenticate with clear text password is wrong, unless you don't care about security.

Answer (score 28):

In order to download a zipped copy of a *private* Bitbucket repository from the command line, use the following:

```
curl --digest --user <username>:<password> https://bitbucket.org/<username>/<repository>/get/<branchname>.zip -o <branchname>.zip
```

where `<username>` and `<password>` are the Bitbucket account name and password, `<repository>` is the repo name and `<branchname>` is the branch. If you'd rather download a specific commit, use the SHA-1 hash of the commit in place of `<branchname>.`

The `--digest` flag is for your security, and is **highly recommended.** It accomplishes authentication so that your username and password are *not* sent in the clear. The `-o` flag sends the output of the curl command to disk as a file, instead of streaming across your terminal screen.

**Note:** Bitbucket's authentication scheme isn't compatible with `wget.` That is why you must use `curl.`

For *public* Bitbucket repositories the command is:

```
curl https://bitbucket.org/<username>/<repository>/get/<branchname>.zip -o <branchname>.zip
```

Or alternately, you may use `wget` for public repositories since no authentication is required:

```
wget https://bitbucket.org/<username>/<repository>/get/<branchname>.zip
```

In addition to `.zip` format, you may download repositories in `.gz` and `.bz2` flavors. Simply replace `.zip` in the code above with either `.gz` or `.bz2`to download the repository in the compressed format of your choice.

Comment: I tried `curl --digest --user <username>:<password> https://bitbucket.org/<usename>/<project>/downloads/<filename> -o <filename>` to download from the Download area, but it doesn't work. Any idea why not?

Comment: Worked like a charm for me. Thanks! Now I created an auto-updater script for my website!

Comment: @FaheemMitha, to download from the Download area, you need to add the `-L` option, like this: `curl -L --digest --user <username>:<password> https://bitbucket.org/<usename>/<project>/downloads/<filename> -o <filename>`

Comment: Is `--digest` necessary since it's over https?

Comment: BitBucket has deprecated and then turned off support for Digest access authentication. [More info.](https://blog.bitbucket.org/2015/04/03/fare-thee-well-digest-access-authentication)

Comment: Note that wget now seems to work with Bitbucket's authentication scheme.  See: [laike9m's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28381930/1448678) and [mstra's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25683149/1448678) answers.

Comment: What you describe works, but it downloads not the repository but a checkout of the specified version of the repository. My connection is very bad, and `git clone` just aborts for a 10MB repo. However I can download a 11MB dump of the latest version easily. How can I get the repo itself with `curl`? (Only the `.git` directory would be good enough.)

Answer (score 11):

> The --digest flag is for your security, and is highly recommended. It accomplishes authentication so that your username and password are not sent in the clear.

This not true.

Bitbucket exclusively uses TLS and so at no point does anything go over the wire in clear text. As a result, Digest provides no benefit over Basic Auth. In fact, considering that Digest is server-initiated, you incur an additional server round-trip requesting the server-provided nonce.

Our use of Digest has been redundant and deprecated ever since we stopped offering unencrypted HTTP access several years ago and was kept only because there were curl-based scripts doing `--digest` as suggested by @GrowlTiger.

In fact, we are about to turn off Digest altogether on May 1st, after which `curl --digest` will cease to work.

More info can be found: https://blog.bitbucket.org/2015/04/03/fare-thee-well-digest-access-authentication/

Comment: This is not an answer to the initial question, but a commentary to another answer. Please re-post as a comment to the offending answer (or attached to the question itself).

Answer (score 8):

For those who want to download single file from private repo on bitbucket, I've tried the above but none worked. Finally I got it working with the below command:

```
wget --user=<user> --password=<password> https://bitbucket.org/<user>/<repo>/raw/master/<filename>
```

Comment: This worked for me too, though I prefer using `--ask-password` rather than `--password=<password>` so as not to have my password visible and/or stored anywhere as plain text.

Answer (score 3):

GrowlTigers answer is great, just an update: with wget it seems to work now, too:

```
wget --user=<username> --password='<password>' https://bitbucket.org/<user>/<repo>/get/<filename>.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

Does the tool you're using support basic authentication credentials in the URL? [Curl request with digest auth in PHP for download Bitbucket private repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319403/curl-request-with-digest-auth-in-php-for-download-bitbucket-private-repository) strongly implies that:

```
curl --user user:pass https://bitbucket.org/user/repo/get/commit.zip >commit.zip
```

works.

Answer (score 1):

I found that this worked in the newer version of Bitbucket

```
repository_list=" a b c"
for repository in ${repository_list}
do
    echo "Getting: ${repository}"
    curl --user userid:password \
         http://bitjira.xxx.com:7990/rest/api/latest/projects/WP/repos/${repository}/archive?format=zip  \
         -o ${repository}.zip
done
```