# Get the latest code from a git remote branch using powershell command

Tags: git, powershell

Is there a simple command in windows powershell to get the latest code from a git remote repository? I have already installed [git posh](https://chocolatey.org/packages/poshgit)

Note:

1. New to both git and powershell.
2. I am **not** creating a repository. I just want to get the code from a remote branch so that I want to build using ms build tool in the next step of the powershell script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use git clone

```
git clone <http or ssh address for the repository>
```

If you have already cloned the repo, you need to checkout the branch then pull it.

```
git checkout <branch name>
git pull
```

If you have no branches available to checkout from remote:

```
git fetch origin
```

And see what branches are available to checkout with:

```
git checkout -v -a
```

Comment: I am sorry if I am not clear by the question, but I dont want to clone the repository. I just want to get the latest code so that I can build it. This is build machine, not development machine.

Comment: Do you already have a local working copy and just want to update it?

Comment: No, I dont have a local working copy. i dont want to create a git repository. i just want the code from the remote so that I can create a build and publish it.

Comment: Github allows you to just download a zip files of all the code if you want to do that. However, it would be much easier to git clone.

Comment: Your last comment nudged me to the right direction. I have to somehow get the zip of the HEAD of the concerned branch. Thanks again for the pointer.

Comment: I should have looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682143/download-private-bitbucket-repository-zip-file-using-http-authentication) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044749/bitbucket-download-source-as-zip) so questions

Comment: Yeah curl would work nicely for that sort of thing if you wanted to use powershell. Downloading the ZIP file through the browser is all good too! I personally find curl a bit annoying at time when copying and pasting the comments because it doesn't always persist the quotation marks and things like that and throws errors.

Comment: You could clone just the current data: `git clone --depth 1 --branch main https://cloneurl`, you end up with a git repo that only has the data for the latest version if the selected branch.