# bitbucket privte repostitory ssh git archive failing

Tags: ssh, bitbucket

I try to get a private repository by doing git archive as follows.

```
git archive --remote=ssh://git@bitbucket.org/your_bitbucket_username/your_repository.git 
--format=zip --output="name_of_your_desired_zip_file.zip" master
```

as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21866783/1977871)

I had set up ssh for windows as explained [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html) and added public key to the bit bucket account.

But I am always getting this error

**Connection to bitbucket.org closed by remote host.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly**

Any idea why this is happening.

The download starts but the download stops well below 2000 kb. Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: `ssh -vvv git@bitbucket.org`

Comment: What does that do?

Comment: it will test if you can authenticate to the bitbucket. But it might not work on Wind**s

Comment: Is there some reason you can't go to the Downloads link for that repo in your browser?