# Private BitBucket repository download

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I am looking at this
[Download private BitBucket repository zip file using http authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682143/download-private-bitbucket-repository-zip-file-using-http-authentication) and trying to implement download of one file.

```
git archive --remote=ssh://git@bitbucket.org/steven/SH/downloads.git --format=zip --output="gz.zip" master
```

As well as

```
git archive --remote=ssh://git@bitbucket.org/steven/SH.git downloads/gz --output output.zip
```

I get - fatal: could not create archive file Permission denied

[image of repo](https://ibb.co/gOi5CR)

Comment: Are you trying to download a file from the Downloads section, or are you trying to get an archive of the repository content? They are separate operations.

Comment: @JimRedmond Download a file.  Is this possible or na?

Comment: Not through SSH.

Comment: @JimRedmond Uh okay. Thanks for that info.  So what exactly did they do in that question I linked then if not download

Comment: @JimRedmond Same issue with github?

Comment: I'd have to check, but "could not create archive file" implies a local permissions issue.

Github does not offer file uploads like Bitbucket does: https://github.com/blog/1302-goodbye-uploads

Comment: @JimRedmond It is sad day when they overlook such a simple, crucial feature.

Answer (score 0):

go to your bitbucket Repository overview page.
Under the Overview heading, there will be a link. copy the link.
open command prompt in your path.
type hg clone (paste the link) --  Your default branch will be download to your path.

Comment: You can't hg clone a git repo.